# Spring Boot - SimpMessagingTemplate is not sending messages to the client in spring boot websocket with spring boot security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-websocket

No matter whatever I do I am not able to send data to the HTML client from controller by using spring boot websocket. I almost tried everything but nothing worked for me. Below is my code.

**This is my AdminTournamentController.class**

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class AdminTournamentController {

@Autowired
private AdminTournamentService adminTournamentService;

@Autowired
private LabelComponent labelComponent;

@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@RequestMapping("/admin/AddTournament")
public String addTournament(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("labelComponent", labelComponent);
    model.addAttribute("adminTournamentModel", new AdminTournamentModel());
    return "/admin/AddTournament";
}

@RequestMapping("/admin/SaveTournament")
@Transactional
public String saveTournament(@ModelAttribute @Valid AdminTournamentModel adminTournamentModel,
        HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("labelComponent", labelComponent);
    try {
        // Here is the convert and send method
        template.convertAndSend("topic/user/Tournaments", adminTournamentModel);
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "/admin/AddTournament";
        }
        if (adminTournamentModel.getTournamentName().trim().isEmpty()) {
            bindingResult.rejectValue("tournamentName", "error", "Tournament name cannot be empty");
            return "/admin/AddTournament";
        }
```

**This is my MessageHandlingController.class**

```
@Controller
public class MessageHandlingController {

@MessageMapping("/admin/SaveTournament")
@SendTo("topic/user/Tournaments")
public AdminTournamentModel newTouramenst(@Payload AdminTournamentModel adminTournamentModel) {
    System.err.println("Over here");
    return adminTournamentModel;
}

}
```

**This is my SecurityConfiguration.class**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").loginProcessingUrl("/validateLogin").failureUrl("/login?error") 
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/successLogin", true)
            .and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("rememberMe").rememberMeCookieName("exidious").tokenValiditySeconds(604800)
            .and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1)
            .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
            .and().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS)
            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/user/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").deleteCookies("exidious")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);
}
```

**This is my WebSocketConfiguration.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/exidious").withSockJS();
}
```

**Here is the client side:- Client side is html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title th:text='${labelComponent.getLabel("AAA045")}'></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/sockjs-client/sockjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="/webjars/stomp-websocket/stomp.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{../css/exidious.css}">
</head>
<body onload="connect();">
<script type="text/javascript">
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/exidious');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, function (frame) {
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);
        stompClient.subscribe('/topic/user/Tournaments', function (tournaments) {
            alert(1);
            tournamentsFunction(tournaments);
        });
    });
    
    function tournamentsFunction(tournaments) {
        $("#greetings").append("<tr><td>" + JSON.parse(tournaments.body) + "</td></tr>");
    }
}
</script>
    <div th:replace="fragments/userHeader" >&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="content">
         <table id="conversation" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Greetings</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="greetings">
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see your client code too? There shouldn't be any problem with your current code, only with the section where you're creating the connection to the websocket on the client side.

Comment: Any stack trace for erros?

Comment: @PatelRomil :- No there is no stack trace for errors

Comment: @user1234SI. :- I have updated my question with client side code too.

Comment: You should configure different endpoints for `@RequestMapping` and `@MessageMapping`. And one more observation is to be careful at the missing `/` from endpoints. And I'm curious about the code section where you send a message to the `@MessageMapping("/admin/SaveTournament")` in order to receive a response.

Comment: @user1234SI. Thank you very much for your answer. It worked like a charm. There are couple of things which I am confused.1) And one more observation is to be careful at the missing / from endpoints.-- I did not understood your point. 2) When I was sending message to websocket from html using same endpoints for RequestMapping and MessageMapping how it was working?

Comment: I mean that you have `@SendTo("topic/user/Tournaments")` while the other endpoints contain the first `/`. It's easy to configure your `connect()` function with some paths and in the end everything looks right but is not working because you need some extra `/` or remove some `/` etc. And for 2) I don't quite understand. You've said that your program is not working. Or you want to understand why it wasn't working?